# Dropdownlist does not keep values on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, viewstate

what i want to do is keeping the values of a dropdownlist with viewstate.
because i keep loosing the values at the momment of pressing a button that adds another row to the gridview, can't find an example with dropdownlists.

Comment: Without code it will be impossible to tell you what is going on.How are you filling the dropdown? What do you have in OnLoad method of the page?

Comment: Post your HTML markup, and cs code

Comment: You probably add the values in the `C#` code and it's not being called again when you postback.

Comment: @Aradmey that is what i want to do but i dont know how to call them back, where do i put the viewstate, how to create on code and retrive when (!Ispostback)

Comment: Show us your code and we'll be able to help you more..

Comment: sorry for not answering before, i found a solution using the gridview rowdatabound events